# Sync a large number of images in ExpressionEngine 2.10.1

Tags: expressionengine

I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.10.1 and have a directory with approx 20,000 images in it. All the image files are in a single directory (there are no sub-directories).

When I attempt to sync the files with EE - under Content > Files > File Upload Preferences > Synchronize - the progress bar will get about 25% along and then hang. There are no errors in the server log relating to it.

I guess this is because I have a large number of files although haven't read anything about limits on the number of files EE can support.

Is there a way to resolve this, e.g. some way to batch sync the files?

Comment: I have the same problem with 19,000 files, also after 2.10.1

Comment: @JohndeBeer I never found a solution to this unfortunately. I think the process to sync the files does actually keep running for longer than the progress bar / Admin panel interface suggests. Because you can see the requests are still running if you use something like Chrome Developer Tools to monitor the network requests. Nonetheless the full sync doesn't happen and it's a real problem!

Comment: As you say, it runs, but after a really long time, mine stops with a white page displaying the page url in text format on the page! After some tracing I can see that the EE sync routine does not even get started, so I am guessing that there is some problem before it even gets there. Fun times. Hard to believe some of the bigger image-hosting sites have not seen this.  BTW, are you using P&T Matrix to hold the images? I do and I thought it might have something to do with it. Later.

Comment: No I wasn't using  P&T Matrix. This was just plain EE 2.10.1 with a large number of files. I'm surprised nobody has encountered it either. I'm wondering if it's possible to run the sync process from a command line rather than using the web interface? If it's the browser that's causing it to time out that could be part of the problem.